# How can I create an animated gif with a small file size?

Tags: pgfplots, pdftex, animations

The only method I know for creating animated gifs with pdflatex is by generating each frame and applying imagemagicks `convert`. The issue is that there is a lot of stuff in all frames

```
pdflatex animation.tex -output-format=pdf
pdfcrop animation.pdf
convert -verbose -delay 10 -loop 0 -density 300 animation-crop.pdf animation.gif
```

[image]

- Original: 1708px x 829px; 2.5MB
- Removing the `[background rectangle/.style={fill=white}, show background rectangle]`: 1.6 MB (but then it looks pixelated / ugly for the characters)
- Downscaling to 1200px: 1.8MB
- Applying [an optimizer](https://ezgif.com/optimize/ezgif-2-0eeb07fb1427.gif): 92.92KiB

Is there any way I can generate a small image with pdflatex, e.g. by not re-drawing the axes all the time?

### Complete Example

```tex
\documentclass[varwidth=false, border=2pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,multido}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
at={(0,0)},
anchor=north east}}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+1}{100}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=white}, show background rectangle]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        grid = major,
        width=16cm,
        height=8cm,
        grid style={dashed, gray!30},
        xmin=-2.1,   % start the diagram at this x-coordinate
        xmax= 4.1,   % end   the diagram at this x-coordinate
        ymin= 0,     % start the diagram at this y-coordinate
        ymax= 17,    % end   the diagram at this y-coordinate
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        ytick={0,2,3,4,8,9,12,16},
        yticklabels={0,2,3,4,8,9,12,16},
        legend cell align=left,
        legend pos=south east,
        legend style={draw=none},
        tick align=outside,
        enlargelimits=false]
      % plot the function
      \addplot[domain=-2:{-1.5 + (9.5*\i/100)}, red, ultra thick,samples=500] {2^x};
      \addplot[domain=-2:{-1.5 + (7.5*\i/100)}, blue, ultra thick,samples=500] {3^x};
      \addplot[domain=-2:{-1.5 + (6.5*\i/100)}, green, ultra thick,samples=500] {4^x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need `\i` from `60` to `100`. I think that it is the reason why your gif has large size.

Comment: There is actually another issue which I couldn't fix : I thought -" 1.5+5.5*\i/100" would be going up to x=4...but it didn't.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much TikZ, so I can't help you with the TikZ problem.

Comment: I realize that people on stack exchange bandy about the term **MVCE**. However, newcomers don't use that terminology and they are ones who want to know who to do this, that, or the other in *LaTeX*. People good with ***LaTeX*** don't look up "how do I compress an animated GIF". In order to make your post accessible to people who don't already know how to compress a GIF, I recommend acoiding the initialism "*MVCE". If you write things like MVCE then guides on how-to-do-x will be readable only by people who already know how to do x. `MVCE` stands for `Minimal Verifiable Complete Example`

Comment: Have you tried playing with various [frame disposal / overlay](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/#dispose) methods? If instead of plotting the whole plot in each frame, you plot only what changed from frame to frame, leaving all other pixels transparent, with "no disposal" you should be able to significantly compress the resulting gif.

Comment: [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) has "filters" - "animation" - "combine"/"optimize for gif" where all frames but the first frame are transparent and just add what is not already there. So you can open your pdf-file in GIMP (hereby select resolution and ensure pages are opened as layers). Then apply "Layer"-"Stack"-"Reverse Layer Order", then apply gif-optimization flters, then "File" - "Export As", select gif/as animation, adjust frame display duration etc and then save as .gif.

Answer (score 3):

Only for compare purpose!

I reproduce your code by [Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/) and I get:

Original file: ~855KB

Gif file: ~1MB

[image]

```
import animate;
settings.tex="pdflatex"; 

animation Ani;

real width=16cm;
real height=8cm;

size(width,height,false);
import graph;

real f(real x){return 2^x;}
real g(real x){return 3^x;}
real h(real x){return 4^x;}
int samples=500;

real xmin=-2.1;
real xmax=4.1;
real ymin=0;
real ymax=17;

for(int a=-5; a<=60;++a)
{
save();
picture pic;
path F=graph(f,-2,-1.5+(9.5*a/100),samples),
     G=graph(g,-2,-1.5+(7.5*a/100),samples),
     H=graph(h,-2,-1.5+(6.5*a/100),samples);

draw(pic,F,red+2.5bp);
draw(pic,G,blue+2.5bp);
draw(pic,H,green+2.5bp);
clip(pic,box((xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax)));

real marginx=.4, marginy=0.05;
for (real i: new real[]{-2,-1.5,-1,-0.5,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4}){
draw((i,ymin)--(i,ymax),linetype(new real[] {10,10})+gray+opacity(30/100)+0.2bp);
draw(scale(0.8)*Label("$"+(string) i+"$",Relative(0)),(i,0)-(0,marginx)--(i,0));
}
for (int j: new int[]{2,3,4,8,9,12,16}){
draw((xmin,j)--(xmax,j),linetype(new real[] {10,10})+gray+opacity(30/100)+0.2bp);
draw(scale(0.8)*Label("$"+(string) j+"$",Relative(0)),(0,j)-(marginy,0)--(0,j));
}

draw(Label("$x$",EndPoint,LeftSide),(xmin,0)--(xmax,0),Arrow(TeXHead));
draw(Label("$y$",Relative(0.99)),(0,ymin)--(0,ymax),Arrow(TeXHead));
add(pic);
Ani.add();
restore();
}
erase();
Ani.movie(BBox(Fill(white)));
```

Why do we need `picture pic`?

-> Because we usually want to display graphs above all.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After you are done using LaTeX to generate a high quality animated GIF you can use a third party program (not LaTeX) in order to compress the GIF ("***compress***" means reduce the file size).

The following website is alright, except that the output is a highly compressed `.mp4`, not an actual `.gif`.

> [www.veed.io/tools/video-compressor/gif-compressor](https://www.veed.io/tools/video-compressor/gif-compressor)